# Phrase Encompassing Pancakes, Waffles and French Toast

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm looking for a phrase that suggests and encompasses such breakfast items as pancakes/crêpes, waffles, and French toast. Essentially any batter- or dough-based foods typically associated with breakfast.

I can't think of much that would be appropriate here. "Fried breakfast food" could refer to fried eggs or sausages, and "fried dough breakfast" just sounds bizarre.

I am aware that the vast majority of people will simply fall back to "pancakes, waffles and french toast", but I'm wondering if there's anything better I can use.

Comment: I suspect that something like "batter-based breakfast food" is about the best you can do.

Comment: Stuff you put maple syrup on?

Comment: *baked breakfast carbohydrates*

Comment: It might be better to just use an open-ended list: *pancakes, waffles, toast, etc*.

Comment: Maybe *”breakfast breads”*?

Comment: @tchrist - But what about scrambled eggs, sausage, hashbrowns, etc.  Don't you put syrup on *everything*?

Comment: @Lawrence pancakes are certainly not baked; French toast is made with a baked ingredient, but the final cooking is also in a pan, and I don't think anyone would describe the cooking effected by a waffle iron as "baking."

Comment: Do you want to include or exclude donuts? What about muffins?

Comment: Breakfast carbs!

Comment: @Lawrence _pancakes, waffles, toast, etc._ is a good idea, but it may be somewhat ambiguous as to what _etc._ stands in for.

Comment: @HotLicks _Don't you put syrup on **everything**?_ **YES**

Comment: Okay, I'm starting to seriously doubt the existence of an unambiguous, serious answer here. "Breakfast carbohydrates" is amusing, but could mean any number of things. "Batter-based breakfast food" is descriptive and fits the bill, but doesn't (for me, anyway) evoke the image of waffles (and French toast isn't even made with batter). (TBH, I was secretly hoping there would be an actual common phrase that people used for these things; seemingly not so.) Thanks anyway, everyone; I'll still accept answers if you think you have a decent one.

Comment: @ThatsJustCheesy - *and French toast isn't even made with batter* -- You've never had real french toast.

Comment: When I was growing up in England, French toast was pre-toasted bread which came in very small slices. That doesn't seem to fit the context here, since you refer to "fried dough breakfast". Although "dough-based foods typically associated with breakfast" would seem to encompass bread, pastries, etc. Could you clarify what exactly the range of items is that fits under the umbrella for which you seek a name?

Comment: @ my previous comment: StackExchange had neglected to show me the answer below, which is a good fit for my question. I'll leave my comment there, but I have an answer that is satisfying.

Comment: @PeterTaylor -- During WWII, my dad learned how to make French toast from a Frenchman.  (I suspect my dad spent a lot of his time in Europe on KP.)  His French toast was made by dipping slices of bread into a batter of egg, cinnamon, brown sugar, and milk, then deep frying in a skillet with a inch of hot oil.  THAT'S how you make French toast!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the menus I've seen that categorize pancakes, waffles, and french toast use a phrase with the word [***griddle***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/griddle) in it: *griddle items* or *from the griddle* or just *griddle* as a heading.

Now, waffles are technically made in a waffle iron (though it's occasionally called a [waffle griddle](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS696US697&q=%22waffle%20griddle%22&oq=%22waffle%20griddle%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l3j0i22i30k1l7.27640.27822.0.28332.2.2.0.0.0.0.115.227.0j2.2.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.2.225....0.Y_Guxkk6vgU)), and eggs and sausage and such are probably made on a griddle, too. But that's the way many restaurants classify things (probably because everything else made on the griddle easily fits into an obvious category, like "breakfast meat" or "eggs").

Some examples:

- [Bob Evans breakfast menu](https://www.bobevans.com/our-restaurants/menu/breakfasts) has a heading "**Griddle**" which includes Crepes, several types of Hot Cakes (AKA pancakes), Belgian Waffles, and two kinds of French Toast.
- The menu for [Chew Chew's Diner](https://www.doordash.com/store/chew-chew-s-diner-toronto-44787/) includes a category "**From the Griddle**" which includes three types each of pancakes and French toast
- [Omni Hotels' Prado Restaurant's breakfast menu](https://www.omnihotels.com/-/media/images/hotels/phxrst/restaurants/menus/phxrst-prado-breakfast-lunch-menu-2015.pdf?la=en) also has a heading "**Griddle**" consisting of pancakes and French toast; the description of their "Full Breakfast Buffet" includes

  > Chef’s Daily Egg Selection / Chef’s Choice of **Griddle Item** / Breakfast Meats / Breakfast Potatoes

And a couple of caveats:

This doesn't actually cover all breakfast foods that are batter- or dough-based, since it will exclude prepared-ahead items like pastries, toasted bread, muffins, and donuts. If you want to include that kind of thing I think you're going to have to go for something wordier and/or less precise, like *flour-based breakfast foods* or *bready/doughy breakfast stuff*. Note that these phrases would also include toast.

Also, the examples are all North American restaurants (Chew Chew's is Canadian, the other two US) so I don't know how well this phrase would be understood elsewhere. On the other hand, I'm not entirely sure other folks would even consider these foods an obvious "category". (I remember the French exchange student who stayed with us when I was in high school thought French toast for breakfast was hilarious: to her, it was something like a dessert, not a main dish for breakfast. I don't know what she made of pancakes and waffles.)

Comment: As a BrE speaker who watches a lot of American TV, I would probably understand this. But the word "griddle" isn't used in BrE, and I wouldn't expect it to be widely understood. Then again, the items the OP mentioned aren't typical breakfast items over here, so a North-American-centric answer is the right way to go. So +1

Comment: This actually works really well… and I'll be using the phrase in a Canadian context, so the categorization won't be a problem. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Glad it helped!